# jQuery ui tabs multiple nav

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery with 2 navigation.

Now I have the classic one:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

<ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab-0">Tab 1 - ref</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 2 - ref</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-0>
// something
</div>
<div id="tab-1>
// something
</div>
```

When the screen resolution is smaller than 640px I want to hide() .nav-tabs and show() .nav-tabs-2. And .nav-tabs-2 to be like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="tab-0">Tab 1 - ref</option>
  <option value="tab-1">Tab 2 - ref</option>
</select>
```

My problem is I don't know how to make 2 navigations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use media queries.

```
@media all and (max-width: 639px) {
.nav-tabs1 {
    display: none;
}
.nav-tabs2 {
    display: initial;
}
}
```

Comment: Try improving your answer by giving a small snippet as example and optionally linking to an external reference.